# Selenium WebDriver can't find Firefox when installed with Homebrew cask

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, homebrew, homebrew-cask

`Homebrew` cask does some app linking magic on Mac OS X. Apparently it's not good enough because Selenium WebDriver looking for the Firefox executable can't find it. The following is an error message from an `RSpec` test run with `Capybara` driving Selenium.

What is a good way to hint the location of the Firefox executable?

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
   Could not find Firefox binary (os=macosx). Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:127:in `path'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:60:in `execute'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:34:in `start_with'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:70:in `start_silent_and_wait'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:35:in `block in launch'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:20:in `locked'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:32:in `launch'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:24:in `initialize'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `new'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
 # /Users/mende/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:13:in `browser'
```

Comment: As the title says, FF is installed via Homebrew cask. It runs fine as a Mac app but it's executable is not discoverable by Selenium-WebDriver.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the error msg says: You have to specify `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path` for custom app paths.

```
# in spec_helper.rb
require 'selenium/webdriver'

Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path =
  "/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/Firefox/latest/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox"
```

---

If you don't want to touch the test framework, you can install firefox to `/Applications` (default path selenium searches for) to make it work without setting the `Binary.path`.

```
brew cask install --appdir="/Applications" firefox
```

Comment: I was looking for a fix on the cask side but it seems none is forthcoming soon so I will accept this answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with how to install firefox to the default dir (which is a fix "on the cask side" you are looking for maybe).

Comment: Nice! The implicit basis for this answer is that by default Cask binaries are symlinked into `/Users/<You>/Applications` but the selenium-driver is looking in the system-wide `/Applications` folder because it is the common default installation path for GUI apps.

Comment: Only the second one (path to the exact binary) works for me. Also had to `require 'selenium/webdriver'`.

Comment: if you are looking to install chromedriver its: brew install --cask --appdir="/Applications" chromedriver

Answer (score 3):

I just added the code for Selenium to look for this directory specifically without needing to set it or change appdir. It will be available in the selenium-webdriver gem 2.49+